# class not found when running maven jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, executable

First of all, I am new to creating maven projects. My java project has 2 dependencies. gson2.2.4, and sqlite-jdbc3.8.11.2. Both dependencies are fine when maven compiles. I have the maven-dependency-plugin exporting my dependencies to the jars root directory. When I try to run the generated jar I get class not found exceptions. sqlite-jdbc jar is right there in the root directory, but it isn't being found. This isn't a "how to compile using maven" it is a my maven doesn't generate a correct classpath problem.

> Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC

Created jar hierarchy:

```
client
  all the class files
META-INF
  maven
    eventually gets to pom.properties and pom.xml
  MANIFEST.MF
server
  main
    Server.class
  other files with .class files
gson-2.2.4.jar
sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2
```

---

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0  
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver  
Built-By: Steve  
Class-Path: .  
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9  
BuildJdk: 1.8.0_65  
Main-Class: server.main.Server
```

pom.xml build tag

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>false</overwritereleases>
            <overWiteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overwriteIfNewer>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifestEntries>
            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>
            <Main-Class>server.main.Server</Main-Class>
          </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</source>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You're not correctly building a JAR having your dependencies. You can't put the dependencies JAR like that at the root of your main JAR. Refer to the linked post to see how to do it.

Comment: I tried putting it into a lib folder, but that didn't work either